# Titanium search view nor sorting out

Tags: titanium

I 'm using Android Titanium Appcelerator.

I had created a search bar for a tableview but it does not sorting the table values, please help:

```
var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({     
    showCancel : false,  
});  
TableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({  
    search : search,  
    searchHidden : true,    
filterAttribute : 'filter',    
 });
```

And I have added `filter = contents;` inside my rowview.

Comment: Plz paste the full code here

Answer (score 3):

This is the basic code.  I append all the text I want to search on into the filter of the tableRow definition.  I then set the filter attribute of my tableROW to the filterAttribute of the tableVIEW.

```
var tableRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height : '70dp',
    layout : 'vertical',
    filter : filterByThis1 + ' ' + filterByThis2
});

var search = Ti.UI.createSearchBar({});


var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    filterAttribute : 'filter',
    search : search
});
```